# Time prepositions

Tags: word-choice, grammar, prepositions

Which of the following is the correct usage?

About 1st week of January
 or
Around the 1st week of January,

if it is during this time period that I want to say, something is going to happen.

Comment: If it happens during the first week of January, why don't you just say that?

Comment: If you are simply asking whether the definite article is required with *first week of January* - the answer is *yes*.

Comment: No, I am in doubt about the preposition to be used. Should it be 'about' or 'around'?

Comment: Be aware that saying you are in doubt is not English so marks your speech and writing as foreign.

Answer (score 1):

If the choice was between 'About 1st week of January' and 'Around the 1st week of January' then the answer would have been the second, 'Around the 1st week of January' but only because of the article 'the.'

Your extra comment reveals something different. 'About/around 1st week of January' would both be wrong without articles.
'About/around the 1st week of January' would both be right, again because of the article.

In other circumstances it might be reasonable to suggest that ‘about’ meant ‘approximately’ in a numeric sense and ‘around’ meant ‘in the vicinity of’ inn a geographic sense but the argument that either would be wrong if they were swapped around would rather tenuous.

For future reference, by all means change the example if the change is either vital or obviously irrelevant; otherwise please never change the example.